# Restrict UITextField from entering 0 as first character without using UITextField delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to achieve this functionality by giving an action to textField object like myTextField.editingChanged

I know this can be easily done by using textField's delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if string == "0" {
       if textField.text!.count == 0 {
          return false
        }
       return true
    }
}
```

But I need to do this in custom method and add it as a target to textField. Surely there must be some way.

Comment: _"But I need to do this in custom method and add it as a target to textField."_ Why? You need to explain what blocks you from simply implementing the delegate method, otherwise it will be hard to come up with an alternative solution to the most obvious and correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add observer on textfield like

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textFieldDidChangeText), name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

and give your custom implementation in below function

```
@objc func textFieldDidChangeText(_ textField: UITextField) { ... }
```

Don't forget to remove observer as well.

Comment: Quoting apple doc "If your app targets iOS 9.0 and later or macOS 10.11 and later, and you used addObserver(_:selector:name:object:), you do not need to unregister the observer." So your last statement "Don't forget to remove observer as well." not so correct :)

Comment: @SandeepBhandari remove observer is not required for specific observer not for all type of observers.